# record timestamps in vb.net wpf project from different windows

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I am build a vb.net/wpf application, which is a sequence of wpf windows. I want to record a timestamp every time a new window opens, or closes, or if user press a button. I am trying to find a solution how to record time when the event occurred relatively to the start of the program. I am not sure how to create  sort of "global" stopwatch and access it from different windows to ask to record a timestamp. What should be the approach ?

Comment: create a class with a static var ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a single object responsible for opening the windows. E.g., that could be the Program class or Wizard class (this sounds like a wizard-kind of UI to me)

When have the Wizard class open each window and wait for it to close by calling `ShowDialog`.

If you do this it is not that hard to timestamp the opening and closing of the windows.

The logging of timestamps when buttons get clicked can be done by making a single object responsible for the logging and passing the object to the functions that need to log.

This can easily pollute the signature of the methods.

There are several ways of solving that but most will create a single, wellknown object (static class) that doesn't need to be passed around.

It might be even better to use kind of container that is able to solve a request for an object based on a required interface. [Castle windsor might be an option](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx)

```
//application starts...
var container = new WindsorContainer();

// adds and configures all components using WindsorInstallers from executing assembly
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());

// instantiate and configure root component and all its dependencies and their dependencies and...
var logger= container.Resolve<ILog>();
logger.Log("Click!");

// clean up, application exits
container.Dispose();
```

Comment: @Tim - yes but not impossible: create a single object for logging the timestamps and pass a reference to that object around where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something as the following. It includes static class, and I pass an object (Dictionary) from window to window. I am not sure if it is right approach, but windows activate each other and close after next window is called showdialog.
Thanks for the help.

```
Public Class HelpTools
Shared startKey As String = "start_time"
Public Shared Sub initializeData(ByRef data As Dictionary(Of String, String), ByVal id As String, ByVal startTime As DateTime, ByVal firstTimeStamp As Double)

    AddStringOutput(data, "id", id)

    Dim start As String = startTime
    AddStringOutput(data, startKey, start)

    AddStringOutput(data, "next_timestamp", firstTimeStamp)



End Sub

Public Shared Sub recordTime(ByRef data As Dictionary(Of String, String), ByVal info As String)


    'Set the StartTime at the begin of the processing
    ' for which you want to capture ElapsedTime
    Dim StartTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(getStringOutput(data, startKey)) 'Now


    'Capture the Elapsed Time here as follows
    Dim ElapsedTime As TimeSpan = Now().Subtract(StartTime)
    'Now we will report the output
    'display format is Hours:Minutes:Seconds
    Dim timestamp As String = String.Format(info & ": elapsed Time : {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", CInt(ElapsedTime.TotalHours), _
    CInt(ElapsedTime.TotalMinutes) Mod 60, _
    CInt(ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds) Mod 60)

    Dim nextTimestampNumber As Integer = getDoubleOutput(data, "next_timestamp")
    AddStringOutput(data, "timestamp_" & nextTimestampNumber, timestamp)
    AddDoubleOutput(data, "next_timestamp", 1)

End Sub

...
end class
```